# Cannot assign type 'myFuncDef *' to 'void (*)(double *, double *)'

Tags: python, c, function, pointers, cython

I am struggling to use the concept of pointer in my `cython` code. The following example is the simplified version of what I am trying to do. I have a function `func` which I would like to feed in a function (a distribution function) as an input parameter. The distribution has two pointer vectors as input variables.

```
from cpython cimport array
import cython
import ctypes
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef void (*myFuncDef)(double *, double *)
from cython.parallel import prange
cdef void func(int* x, double* hx, void(*func)(double*, double*), int n):
      def int i
      for i from 0 <= i < n:
          func[0](&x[i], &hx[i])
      return

cpdef void Lognormal(double* u, 
                  double* yu):
      #evaluate log of normal distribution
      yu=-u*u*0.5
      return

def foo(np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] x,
        np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] hx,
        myFuncDef distribution, int k):
    cdef np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] sp
    cdef int num=len(x)
    cdef int j
    for j from 0 <= j <k:
        func(&x[0],&hx[0],&distribution, num)
        sp[j]=hx[0]
    return sp
```

So I would like to used the `Lognormal` function as an input for `foo` function. I get the following error message:

```
Cannot assign type 'myFuncDef *' to 'void (*)(double *, double *)'
```

I will appreciate for any suggestion to fix this bug.

Comment: Your code has a lot of compiler errors, so maybe you should start small, compiling one function after another. `myFuncDef distribution` does not work? So don't use the fancy ctypedef, use directly `void (*distribution)(double *, double *)`. When everything compiles, you can go back and add syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ead when I compile foo function with your suggestion change I get this error:Cannot convert Python object argument to type `void (*)(double *, double *)` because it is a `python` function, any other suggestion to fix this bug?

Comment: So maybe `foo` cannot be a python-function but must be `cdef`?

Comment: @ead `foo` function is the main function that I want to import in my python code, if I'd define it as `cdef` function, then it is not accessible for python, is it?

Comment: @ead Do you have any suggestion to fix `foo` function in order to be able to pass a pointer function as its argument?

Comment: It's hard to make a suggestion based on your question. There is no such thing as  a function pointer in python - all functions are objects.  But feel free to ask a new question with would provide a better description and a minimal example (because now it is far from minimal).

Comment: @ead well I can not make it more simpler than what it is right now.

Comment: @ead I posted another question to solve my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423468/pass-different-c-functions-with-pointer-arrays-as-it-argument-to-a-class). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one too many layers of pointer (the standard issue raised to argue against `typedef`s for pointers).  Just drop the `&` from `&distribution`; it's already the function pointer you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It resolves that bug but I get new error message regarding `foo` function as follows: `Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'myFuncDef'`. Any suggestion to get rid of this?

Comment: `Error compiling Cython file:
 def foo(np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] x,
        np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] hx,
        myFuncDef distribution, int k):`

Comment: would you please clarify how I should define function `distribution` in the `foo` function in order that it won't raise error message? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my expertise here.  You might want to ask a new question (if the discussion with ead isn't enough).