# pass different "C" functions with pointer arrays as the function argument to a class

Tags: python, c, class, pointers, cython

I am trying to pass different functions which have pointers as arguments to a python function. One example of the input function as input parameter is the given `normal` function:

**Sample.pyx**

```
from cpython cimport array
import cython
import ctypes
cimport numpy as np
cpdef void normal(np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] u, 
                  np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] yu, 
                  np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] ypu):

      cdef int i
      cdef int n=len(u)
      for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
          yu[i]=-u[i]*u[i]*0.5                                                               
          ypu[i]=-u[i]                                                                    
      return                                                     
cdef class _SampleFunc:
     cdef void (*func)(double *, double *, double *)

cdef void sample(int* x, double* hx, double* hxx, void(*func)(double*, double*, double*), int n):
      def int i
      for i from 0 <= i < n:
          func[0](&x[i], &hx[i], &hxx[i])
      return 
cdef class myClass:
     sample_wrapper = _SampleFunc() 
     sample_wrapper.func = Null
     def foo(np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] x,
             np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] hx,
             np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] hxx,
             _SampleFunc sample_func, 
             int k):
         cdef np.ndarray[ndim=1, dtype=np.float64_t] sp
         cdef int num=len(x)
         func = sample_func.func
         assert func is not NULL, "function value is NULL"
         cdef int j
         for j from 0 <= j <k:
             sample(&x[0],&hx[0], &hxx[0], func, num)
             sp[j]=hx[0]
         return sp
```

**test.py**

```
import numpy as np
from sample import *
x = np.zeros(10, float)
hx = np.zeros(10, float)
hpx = np.zeros(10, float)

x[0] = 0
x[1] = 1.0
x[2] = -1.0
def pynormal(x):
    return -x*x*0.5,-x

hx[0], hpx[0] = pynormal(x[0])
hx[1], hpx[1] = pynormal(x[1])
hx[2], hpx[2] = pynormal(x[2])
num=20
ars=myClass()
s=ars.foo( x, hx, hpx, normal, num)
```

Running the `test.py` code I am getting this error:

```
'ars._SampleFunc' object has no attribute 'func'
```

I am trying to write a wrapper for different `C` functions which have three pointer arrays as their argument. My conclusion so far was that it can be done with a class, since the class can be accessible in python. I am wondering how I can pass the `C` functions with pointer arrays as argument to `myClass` class?

**Update: Normal function**

```
cdef void normal(
                 int n,
                 double* u, 
                 double* yu, 
                 double* ypu
                ):          
      cdef int i          
      for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
          yu[i]=-u[i]*u[i]*0.5                                                               
          ypu[i]=-u[i]                                                                    
      return
```

Comment: This cannot be possibly the *shortest* example that you could come up with.

Comment: to elaborate on @AnttiHaapala,   _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: for example, the function pointer could be `void(*func)(double)`, then you would need much less code to produce a working example.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have already tried to ask my question in shorter description but no one give a proper answer. I am wondering the purpose of stackoverflow is educational or just giving as short as possible answers to get upvotes for answer providers without giving deep answers.

Comment: @ead I want that the pointers which I give as inputs to the `func` carry the updates of their values. If I pass just a normal variable as argument, then defining python function does the job and actually I do not  need to suffer a lot of trouble to define a `c` function.

Comment: But do you need all 3 pointers for the sake of this example? And your problem is to pass a function pointer, no matter how simple it is, isn't? I would say, which arguments this function has, doesn't really matter.

Comment: My understanding of what you're trying to do is that you have a C function with an interface that you can't change that takes a function pointer (`sample`). The function pointer accepts C arrays (as `double*`). You want to be able to convert a Python callable to this function pointer? Unfortunately this is basically impossible to do in Cython since it involves dynamic code generation (Python callables have quite a bit of state, which you have no way of passing).

Comment: You can do it with ctypes or CFFI though (search for "callbacks" in their documentation) - I can give an working example at some point later (if you/nobody else does it first)

Comment: @DavidW I want somehow write a python wrapper for `sample` function. Well, my original code has another function encapsulated in the foo function that initialize the value of `x` and `hx` and update them, after that it calls the `sample` function. I want to write a python wrapper for all of these and it would be able to get `normal` function which is a `c` function as an argument.

Comment: @Dalek all this information should be in the question, **not** in the comments.

Comment: @Dalek Do you only want to be able to call it with `normal` (reasonably easy) or do you want to call it with arbitrary functions (more difficult)? The other problem is that `normal` has no way of knowing the length of the arrays from `double*`.

Comment: @DavidW I'd like to be able to call any arbitrary function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to deal with is that a function of signature `cdef void (*func)(double *, double *, double *)` **does not pass the array length**. You can't know how long these arrays are, and thus you can't safely access their elements. The sensible thing is to change the function signature to pass a length too:

```
cdef void (*func)(double *, double *, double *, int)
```

What is extra confusing is that you seem to be iterating over the same axis of a 1D array in both `normal` and `sample`. I suspect that isn't what you want to do, but I'm not going attempt to fix that.

---

Essentially your problem is that you want to pass an arbitrary Python callable as a C function pointer. The bad news is that Cython can't do it - a Python callable has a significant amount of information associated with it, while a C function pointer is simply the address of some executable memory. Therefore a C function pointer does not have the space available to hold the information in a Python callable. In order to make this work you need to generate code at runtime, which Python can't do.

[I've recommended the ctypes standard library module as a solution to similar problems previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829), since it can [create a function pointer from a Python callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions). There is a simpler but more limited solution if you only want to call `cdef` Cython functions.

### ctypes

Here's a minimal example which demonstrates how to implement the idea:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

ctypedef void (*func_t)(int, double *)

cdef void sample(int n, double* x, func_t f):
    f(n,x)

def call_sample(double[::1] x,
                f):

    def func_wrapper(n, arg1):
        # x is a slightly opaque ctypes type
        # first cast it to a ctypes array of known size
        # and then create a numpy array from that
        arg1_as_ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_double*n).from_address(ctypes.addressof(arg1.contents))
        return f(np.asarray(arg1_as_ctypes_array))


    FTYPE = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, # return type
                             ctypes.c_int, # arguments
                             ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
    f_ctypes = FTYPE(func_wrapper) # convert Python callable to ctypes function pointer

    # a rather nasty line to convert to a C function pointer
    cdef func_t f_ptr = (<func_t*><size_t>ctypes.addressof(f_ctypes))[0]

    sample(x.shape[0], &x[0], f_ptr)


def example_function(x):
    # expects a numpy array like object
    print(x)

def test():
    a = np.random.rand(20)
    print(a)
    call_sample(a,example_function)
```

I realise that there's some slightly messy conversion between ctypes and Cython - this is unavoidable.

A bit of explanation: I'm assuming you want to keep the Python interface simple, hence `example_function` just takes a numpy array-like object. The function passed by ctypes needs to accept a number of elements and a pointer to match your C interface.

The ctypes pointer type (`LP_c_double`) can do do indexing (i.e. `arg1[5]`) so it works fine for simple uses, but it doesn't store its length internally. It's helpful (but not essential) to change it to a numpy array so you can use it more generally and thus we create a wrapper function to do this. We do:

```
arg1_as_ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_double*n).from_address(ctypes.addressof(arg1.contents))
```

to convert it to a known length ctypes array and then

```
np.asarray(arg1_as_ctypes_array)
```

to convert it to a numpy array. This shares the data rather than makes a copy, so if you change it then your original data will be changed. Because the conversion to a numpy array follows a standard pattern it's easy to generate a wrapper function in `call_sample`.

(In the comments you ask how to do the conversion if you're just passing a `double`, not a `double*`. In this case you don't have to do anything since a ctypes `double` behaves exactly like a Python type)

### Only `cdef` functions

If you're certain the functions you want to pass will always be `cdef` functions then you can avoid ctypes and come up with something a bit simpler. You first need to make the function signature match the pointer exactly:

```
cdef void normal(int N, double *x): # other parameters as necessary
    cdef double[::1] x_as_mview = <double[:N:1]>x # cast to a memoryview
    # ... etc
```

You should then be able to use your definition of `SampleFunc` almost as is to create module level objects:

```
# in Cython
normal_samplefunc = SampleFunc()
normal_samplefunc.func = &normal

# in Python
s=ars.foo( x, hx, hpx, normal_samplefunc, num)
```

`ars.foo` is the way you wrote it (no `ctypes` code):

```
func = sample_func.func
# ...
sample(..., func,...)
```

This code will run quicker, but you want be able to call `normal` from Python.

---

### Python interface

You mention in the comments that you'd also like the be able to access `normal` from Python. You're likely to need a different interface for the Python function and the one you pass to C, so I'd define a separate function for both uses, but share the implementation:

```
def normal(double[::1] u, # ... other arguments
           ):
   # or cpdef, if you really want
   implementation goes here

# then, depending on if you're using ctypes or not:
def normal_ctypes(int n, u # other arguments ...
   ):
   u_as_ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_double*n).from_address(ctypes.addressof(x.contents))
   normal(u_as_ctypes_array, # other arguments
                )

# or
cdef void normal_c(int n, double* u # ...
              ):
   normal(<double[:N:1]>x # ...
          )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and description. I will try to apply your answer to my code.

Comment: A comment and question is that I want the `normal` function would be callable from python code. If I make it, in the way you described on the top, I can not access it in python. Well, Do you think the way I coded my `normal` function is wrong in this context?

Comment: The issue is that for the normal function to be callable from C it needs to _exactly_ match the C signature. For it to be callable from python it needs to accept Python types (i.e. not C pointers). What you probably want to do is to write a Python/Cython version and C version. The C version convert the pointers to a memoryview or numpy array as shown above, and then call the Python version.

Comment: Sorry about my naive questions but I am confused whether the `cpdef` type defining normal function, the way I did above, is right or not? Then can it be used for the pointer function as you defined in your answer? Because I tried to change my code according your comments but kept above definition of the `normal` function, I got this error :`f = FTYPE(f) # convert Python callable to ctypes function pointer
TypeError: invalid result type for callback function`

Comment: I changed the `cpdef void normal` by adding an extra input argument for the size of vector `u`. Then I compiled the code and ran my `test.py` code. For the `sample` function, I got this error message:`File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line ..., in 'calling callback function'
TypeError: Argument 'u' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got LP_c_double)`

Comment: @Dalek I've added an illustration of how I'd go about creating a function that can be called from both Python and C (by creating two versions). If I use my minimal example and change `example_function` to `cpdef` it works fine, so I don't know where your type error comes from. I also don't know about your "argument 'u' has incorrect type".

Comment: the `normal_ctypes` is the function which I can call from my python and pass as an argument to `call_sample` function, right?

Comment: No. `normal` is a function you can call from Python. `normal_ctypes` is a function that you can pass as an argument to `call_sample` but which you aren't really recommended to call from Python.

Comment: but My main question is how can I call from my python script the`call_sample` function and pass a python version of `normal` function as an argument.

Comment: @DawidW the `call_sample` function is a python function, so it can be imported to my python code but what is the reason behind it that you do not recommend to import `call_sample` and `normal_ctypes` to the python code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have a few final questions. If you would kindly answer, I will be really grateful. In the case that pointer just refers to a double value instead of a pointer array, what is the substitution for this line in your answer :`x_as_ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_double*n).from_address(ctypes.addressof(x.contents))` in `normal_ctypes` function to return the address of the pointer?

Comment: One thing that I am still confused is that how to write a python wrapper for `normal_c` function that can be callable from a python script and can be passed to `call_sample` when I will call this function also in my python script?

Comment: To be honest that's hard. There's a choice between writing code that takes Python callables (but might be slower) or writing code that takes C function pointers (which might be quicker but is definitely less easy to use). I don't think there's a good way of doing what you want with `normal_c`.

Comment: I just wrote another function in my `cython` script and used the `normal` function and it is working. Thanks a lot.